# Array of points => Outline path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have an array of about 100-400 points, and I want to find the shortest path around all of them. Yes, I know this is a classic case of travelling salesman, but here's some stuff that may simplify it:

Most points are adjacent to other points, since they form the edges of a transparent-background image.

So I programmed a simple "pathfinder" that picks a point, then looks for adjacent points to try and navigate around the shape. It works, but only if the image is simple enough. Here's an example:

[image: example]

As you can see, the Pikachu outline was calculated perfectly into a single path. However, the Raichu features some narrow areas that completely fail to connect suitably. This algorithm would also fail on more complex sprites such as this one:
[Shedinja http://static.pokefarm.org/_img/pkmn_m/292.png](http://static.pokefarm.org/_img/pkmn_m/292.png) Where the two parts aren't even connected. In a best case I'd have two paths.

So basically, I need to know how to trace single shapes more reliably, and how to join two paths by their closest points into a single path.

Comment: Interesting project…What’s the little halo'ed turtle called?  A question: When drawing your turtle, would you want a path that works like a “sticker” and encloses from left-wing to halo-top to right-wing (a single path that has white space between the halo and turtle).  Or would you want 1 path that connects the left-wing and halo by a 1 pixel wide “connector”.  Or would you want a compound path that draws the halo and then does a “moveTo” and then draws the turtle.

Comment: It's a Shedinja. In my White 2 game my Shedinja is nicknamed "Exodia" :D Anyway, your second suggestion is correct: the "connector" is the option I want. The project is to get a path that can then be morphed, to animate the evolution of a Pokémon.

Comment: It’d be easier to start with the image. Can you use it instead? If you only have the array of points, you can get back the transparent areas by starting transparent and toggling transparency at every edge point encountered.